# How to simply load List<string> to table in SQL Server Compact 2008?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to load (insert) List into SQL Server Compact 2008 table in simpler way than via looping each record in List and inserting it into database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a single query to do what you want and run the whole query (which will save you from having n calls to ExecuteNonQuery() ), but that still requires looping to generate the query (and a bunch of string building which is just not fun :( )...